# Update $PATH variable permanently

Tags: bash, terminal, path, reset, gedit

Apologies if this duplicate but a lot of other threads are years old.

I want to update my $PATH variable permanently so it doesn't reset everytime I quit Terminal. I have seen people suggest to run the following:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

But this returns:

```
-bash: gedit: command not found
```

I have used Spotlight to search my hard disk for the `.bashrc` file and can't find it. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `gedit` is a gnome text editor, use `nano` or something native to OS X instead.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need an editor for that, you can do this using `bash`'s output redirection operation.

For example, to add `/foo/bar` you current `PATH`, append (`>>`) to  `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH":/foo/bar' >> ~/.bashrc
```

To view the content to STDOUT too, use `tee -a`:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH":/foo/bar' | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

the . before the file means it's hidden so that's probably why it didn't show, just like if you do `ls` from your home folder you won't see it but `ls -la` will

to edit your file I would suggest using vi instead if gedit is not available

`vi ~/.bashrc`